# Same audit showed up again

Tags: support, status-completed, review-queues, review-audits

I passed [an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11087355) on LQP. Later that day, that audit showed up again when reviewing.

I've never encountered it before so that seemed weird. Is it OK for this to happen?

[image: red Circle]

Comment: Congratulations! You passed the audit (again).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We modified the review queues so that users cannot be audited on questions they already reviewed. We hope that solves your issues!

Comment: So at what rate does a very active reviewer, 40 reviews per day, run out of possible audits?

Comment: That's a valid concern. The posts for audit are generated from recent posts which community rated as "good" or "bad". That means that on sites with more traffic there's not much risk of running out of possible audits, as the pool of questions is big.

On smaller sites we face the issue: the original pool is rather small, so we either reuse the posts or we accept that the reviewers will run out of questions.

Comment: A middle ground solution would be to extend the period from which the audit tasks are taken, thus expaning the pool of questions for audit.

It could be done, with consideration that we may audit people on outdated questions. We would have to evaluate the risks of possible lower quality of audit questions by that action.

So, the pool of audits can be extended to use older questions, if needed and if it does not lower quality of the audit.

Comment: @marrados What do you mean by "... thus _expaning_..."? Is it a typo?

Comment: ooops, yes. I meant expanding the pool. Basically, if the pool of audit questions is too small, we can include older questions in the pool, but we should be careful not to lower the quality of audit.

Comment: [Review audit on post I already review audited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424456/review-audit-on-post-i-already-review-audited)

Answer (score 33):

Audits are randomly selected, so... It's not common, but nothing stops you from getting the same one twice.

Comment: That's the problem with randomness http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25