# How big is the pool of audits? What's the probability of getting the same audit twice?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits

Today I got an audit: [A: Asynchronous email processing in Java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12158679)

And then I got *the same audit* two post later. ***Congratulations!** You don't suffer from extreme amnesia!*

[image: audit twice, with two posts in between]

This has happened before: [I reviewed the same edit suggestion twice?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262000/i-reviewed-the-same-edit-suggestion-twice)

What I want to know though, is how likely this is to happen.

How big is the pool of audits?

Comment: It's apparently greater than zero.

Comment: Now the probability should be zero :) See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315848/same-audit-showed-up-again/420274#420274

Comment: Still kinda curious about how big the audit pool is, though I guess the number changes as audits age out and newer ones filter in. Plus I don't think anyone can determine how many "known bad" audits there are without mod tools or more.

Comment: @NewEnglandcottontail "users cannot be audited on questions they already reviewed" (from the linked answer). So it should now be a 0% chance of getting the same audit again.

Answer (score 4):

The likelihood of it happening more than once now is zero* since they just pushed a change to fix that, as answered in *[Same audit showed up again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315848/same-audit-showed-up-again)*.

* - Until they make a change in the future that breaks or changes this, of course.