# Review audit on post I already review audited

Tags: bug, status-review, review-queues, review-audits

I just saw a new audit for [Why does the Beautiful Soup package not work in my Python project although I used "pip install beautifulsoup4"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75938222/why-the-beautifulsoup4-package-does-not-work-on-my-python-project-although-i-use).

As the link of the question seemed visited, and the question isn't tagged by some tag I'm watching, I checked in the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75938222/timeline). There are two audits, and it appears that I'm the reviewer of both: [Today](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/34312585), [Last week](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/34263518).

I see a question that can be related [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317101/review-audit-for-a-post-that-i-already-reviewed) about a review audit on which you already made something (his case: review, my: review audit).

It seems to be a bug as it doesn't require to be paying attention, as there is a visual difference.

Note: It appeared a second time for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76108428/10952503), audit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/34394217) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/34431190)

Comment: The purpose of audits is to make sure you pay attention. The evidence shows you do. We're all good.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420274/6083675) where they said this was fixed.

Comment: The fact that you noticed that proves that you were paying attention and weren't just robo-reviewing (which is the point of audits). Keep up the good work!

Comment: I've changed this to a bug report and escalated it for Dev review since [that was supposed to have been fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420274/2370483) (h/t Laurel)